# choose certain words from a variable

Tags: r, grepl

I want to create a dummy variable y condition on the variable x where x is a descriptive variable including a text. if x has certain words as "good" or "bad" or "ugly" then I want y=1 otherwise y=0.

It works for a single word

`df$y <- ifelse(grepl("\\<good\\>",df$x)== TRUE,1,0)`

but I don't know how to do it for a list of words. I tried this but it gives all values of y equal to zero

`keywords <- c("good","bad","ugly")`

`df$y <- ifelse(paste0('\\b',keywords,'\\b',df$x)== TRUE,1,0)`

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: `as.numeric(grepl(paste0(keywords, collapse = "|"), df$x))`

Comment: You can use `|` to seperate the different search terms: `df$y <- ifelse(grepl("(good|bad|ugly)",df$x),1,0)`

Comment: @RonakShah thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to use `grep`??

This may be a solution:

```
df <- data.frame(x=c("good", "bad", "bad", "ugly", "something"))

df
          x
1      good
2       bad
3       bad
4      ugly
5 something

 df$y <- ifelse(df$x %in% c("good", "bad", "ugly"), 1, 0)

df
              x y
    1      good 1
    2       bad 1
    3       bad 1
    4      ugly 1
    5 something 0
```

Comment: or `df$y <- as.numeric(df$x %in% c("good", "bad", "ugly"))`